# codeigniter permissible user actions

Tags: codeigniter

hi typically a codeigniter mvc controller accepts an id as a parameter for a controller function. For example:
/photo/edit/1

A user would edit image id 1 from the photo controller. What is the best practice to prevent a user from editing someone else’s image..for example editing id 2? Restriction has to include more than just verifying a logged in user, because a logged in user will still be able to edit image 2.

I was thinking that i would write a library that implements a permission function, that is called on all controller functions. I would pass the user id and the url to the library function which would contain logic to verify if a user could execute that function or in this case edit an image.

The problem i see is..it will be tedious to write the logic code for all functions of my site, as each is different logic. Is there a better generally practiced way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You generally handle the checking in the controller itself, so if, for instance you have the currently logged in user, and the photo object from the db, just store the photo's owner in the db record and compare them.

It really is not all that tedious, you are simply verifying ownership of the object before processing actions on it.

example...

```
if ($the_user->id == $the_photo->owner_id) {
    //allow their actions
}
else {
    redirect('/');   //if not, kick em out
}
```